# How to fetch each value from Array of strings inside an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array inside an array named as officeList in the following format :-

```
(
        (
        Prospect,
        Propose
    ),
        (
        Open,
        Fund,
        Propose
    ),
        (
        Settle,
        Review
    )
)
```

Problem is I got this array by converting the JSON file into an array and as a result of that I got this array of string inside an array. What I want is to fetch each value one by one like : "prospect", "propose", etc.

I am using following code to fetch data :

```
for (int i = 0;i<[_officelist count];i++)
{
    id val=[officeSize objectAtIndex:i];
    CGFloat val1=[val floatValue];
    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20,val1,15)];

    newLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_officelist[i]];

    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    [self.roadmapCollectionView addSubview:newLabel];

    x=x+val1;
    }
```

Comment: You need another loop to loop over each element of `_officelist[i]` ?

Comment: your code having bug, officelist and officeSize count may be mist match so you can not write id val=[officeSize objectAtIndex:i]; directly

Comment: if i am not using id type to convert NSArray to CGFloat, then what to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_officelist count]; i++)
{
    NSArray *valList=[_officelist objectAtIndex:i];

    CGFloat val1 = [valList floatValue]; // Your Float val


    for (int j = 0; j < [valList count]; j++)
    {
         UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20,val1,15)];

         newLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",valList[j]];

         newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

         [self.roadmapCollectionView addSubview:newLabel];
    }

    x=x+val1;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *objArr in jsonArr) {
    for (NSString *str in ObjArr) {
        [arr addObject:str];
    }
}
```

Here `jsonArr` is the array that you getting from response. Now use `arr` to access every object that you want.

Hope this will help you